# Hibernate Core Jar migration from hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar to hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence, ehcache

```
     <bean id="entityManagerFactory"        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
     <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"/>
          <property name="jpaProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
            hibernate.query.substitutions=true 'Y', false 'N'
               hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
            hibernate.generate_statistics=true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
        </value>
    </property>`
```

"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name         entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/wmInfraWebContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArchiveDescriptor reused; can URLs be processed multiple times?

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArchiveDescriptor reused; can URLs be processed multiple times?
 at  org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.validateReuse(AbstractScannerImpl.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar:5.4.24.Final]"
```